# How do I change the settings of Adobe Flash on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint

If I have Adobe Flash installed on my device running Linux Mint 11 and 12, how do I change the settings on it apart from visiting the Adobe website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On [adobe's page](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager.html), (under "who uses the settings manager"), but I can't find that menu option in my Mint installation.
Instead, as a quick work around, just right click on a flash file (.swf) that is loaded in a browser and pick the plain "Settings" to get the local settings.